# pyodbc insert into SQL Server db table stopped committing. Why?

Tags: sql-server, insert, pyodbc

I have a python script that has been inserting into a SQL Server table for a few weeks since I wrote it.  Suddenly it stopped inserting and I can see that it looks like a COMMIT problem because the Primary Key Identity ID column in the table increments - if I do a T-SQL insert in SSMS, I can see that several ID values have been skipped.  The rows seem to be inserted but are rolled back by the look of it.  I've restarted the SQL Server instance and restarted the VS Code app I am using to run the script from. No success. No errors from python/pyodbc. I've run out of ideas.  Any suggestions?

```
    import pyodbc 

    SQL_DRIVER = 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
    SQL_OUTPUT_TABLE = "test"
    SERVER = "myServer"
    DATABASE = "myDB"

    def main():
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={'+SQL_DRIVER+'};SERVER='+SERVER+';DATABASE='+DATABASE+';Trusted_Connection=yes')
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()

        tsql : str = "insert into [dbo].[test](col1) values ('stuff');"
        cursor.execute(tsql)
        cursor.commit
        cnxn.close

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Tried alternative SQL drivers. Created the test script you see here to reduce the scope as much as possible. Service restarts, etc.  Can also successfully insert rows directly from within SSMS to the table.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem. cursor.execute followed by conn.commit fixed it.

```
import pyodbc 

SQL_DRIVER = 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
SQL_OUTPUT_TABLE = "test"
SERVER = "DESKTOP-GBCJUII"
DATABASE = "xen_mints"


conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={'+SQL_DRIVER+'};'
                      'Server='+SERVER+';'
                      'Database='+DATABASE+';'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO '''+SQL_OUTPUT_TABLE+''' (col1)
                VALUES
                ('stuff')
                ''')
conn.commit()
```